# Creating a script to automate submitting something on a webpage

Tags: bash, shell, web, scripting

I want to create a script, which accesses a website behind a login (with 2FA) and press the submit button every x seconds.

Unfortunately, I am a total Shell noob, but I already automated the process with the Chrome extensions "Kantu Browser Automation", but the extension has limits on the looping and a looping timeout.

Answer (score 1):

use curl command for this and put it crontab.

curl:
https://curl.haxx.se/

you have to use POST method.

crontab:
https://crontab.guru/